# integration of $e^{-(Y-x)^2 - x^2}$

Tags: integration

Say I have a function $f(K_\alpha) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-\frac{(D-K_\alpha)^2}{2}} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{\frac{-K_\alpha^2}{2}}$.

I want to get the integral of $f(K_\alpha)$ over all $K_\alpha$.

$\int_{K_\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-\frac{(D-K_\alpha)^2}{2}} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{\frac{-K_\alpha^2}{2}}$

I started like this.

$\int_{K_\alpha} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-\frac{(D-K_\alpha)^2}{2}} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{\frac{-K_\alpha^2}{2}} dK_\alpha \\
= \int_{K_\alpha} \frac{1}{\pi} e^{-K_\alpha^2+DK_\alpha-(D^2/2)} \\
$

I am not sure what to do after this.

Comment: What is $K_{\alpha}$?

Comment: In my original problem K_\alpha is a Kernal used in a Gaussian Process.

Comment: Ah you might want to add additional details so people know the ranges and values that this variable can take so it helps people answer

Comment: Say I assume a Radial Basis Function. Can I say that the kernel generates values between 1 and 0? I'm not sure how to define the range. Or should Ijust say values beteen $a$ and $b$

Comment: I personally don't know off hand, just helping potential answers get some information